# Get current user session from external script in Joomla 3.5

Tags: php, session, joomla

I am trying to get Joomla 3.5 user session outside joomla. My Joomla site is in subdomain (x.abc.com), I need to check if user is logged in, in main domain (abc.com) which is not Joomla.

I tried below code as per some suggestions found on stackoverflow

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', '../x.abc.com/');
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'libraries'.DS.'joomla'.DS.'factory.php' );

$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
$user =& JFactory::getUser();

echo $user->name;
```

It doesn't seems to work with new version of Joomla. It returns blank output. Please help

Comment: Make sure you have error reporting maxed out, and also dump out each line as you go and see where it dies.  That code looks old in that DS has been unnecessary for a long time.  But for example notice that your JPATH_BASE includes a slash at the end and then you are putting another slash in your require_once statements.

Comment: This script works fine in the same domain, inside the Joomla base directory. But it is not working outside the base directory (in another sub domain).  I tried setting cookie domain like '.abc.com' but no result :(